# Image not showing despite correct folder structure and working on local machine - Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: folder structure]

[image: browser error]

I deployed the build/web folder with Firebase hosting. The exact same process, code and folder structure work on another project of mine.

[image: pubspec]

I have double-checked my pubspec.yaml as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, in development mode Flutter recognizes the assets without specifying the full path but I have to write it in full for the build to make sense of it.

Answer (score 3):

The Container has no height and width to display the decoration.. Also add assets to the path.

```
Container(
  height: 100,
 width: 100,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   Image: DecorationImage(
      ...
   )
 )
)
```

Comment: I don't think so. In the app that works, it's the same folder structure in both build and root as the one that does'nt work and I reference the image the same way.

Comment: can you add how you added the image in pubspec.yaml please?

Comment: it's done just now

Comment: I missed that you haven't added height and/or width to the container.. Edited my answer

Comment: also please add assets/roadmap.jpg the path you added in pubspec shows that you have added image in assets

Comment: OK adding assets made it work

Comment: but do you know why it works without it in another app? Same pubspec, same folder structure

Comment: Not sure maybe its added in the root folder also in the other project

Comment: Yeah actually I understood at the same time as posting the comment.